# Old XIB is loaded every second time I load my app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, xib

I have a very strange problem.

Sometimes when I launch my app (on iPhone device or in Xcode iOS 5.1 Simulator) I got an old version of the XIB I'm doing changes with. Anyone have any tip on what could be wrong?

Here is the code from where i launch the XIB:

```
MapKitDragAndDropViewController *spview = [[MapKitDragAndDropViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:spview animated:YES];
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the nib name???

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem! I had two xib-files. One for iPhone and one for iPad version. Both had same name. removed one because the view suits both formats.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try cleaning your project?? Also remove the app from device/simulator and clean and try installing it again.

Comment: Yes, I have cleaned over and over again. Very strange that it works with updated XIB at firs build, old at second build, updated XIB on third build, old at fourth... and so on.